# get freetime between to dates from another table

Tags: mysql

with this mysql syntax I can get all dates from tomorrow until today+30 days with a 1 hour interval from 14 to 18 o'clock.

```
SELECT 
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL day.seq DAY), INTERVAL hour.seq HOUR) as freetime
FROM 
seq_0_to_30 AS day, 
seq_14_to_18 AS hour
HAVING freetime NOT IN ( SELECT `start` FROM `events`);
```

The having line should search for booked events in the table events.
In this table are columns like start and end.
for example:

```
start: 2021-07-20 16:00:00
end: 2021-07-20 17:00:00
```

this dates / time should not be visible as freetime. that works with the syntax above.
BUT. If I have a booked event like this:

```
start: 2021-07-20 16:00:00
end: 2021-07-20 19:00:00
```

(more than 1 hour), my query works not fine.
I get freetime like this:

```
2021-07-01 14:00:00
2021-07-01 15:00:00
2021-07-01 17:00:00
2021-07-01 18:00:00
```

And this is correct because I checked with my having line only the start value.
How I have to modify the query, that both values (start and end) will be checked.

The correct result should be:

```
2021-07-01 14:00:00
2021-07-01 15:00:00
```

Because from 16 to 18 is an event in my events table available.

Comment: Please post some sample data from both the tables and then post the expected result.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=5ad658bcdc6e745d342605db5f6c9dd9 but this fiddle show another result. the result 2021-07-01 16:00:00 will not shown for me

Answer (score 1):

`seq_0_to_30 AS day` is a lovely feature, but it's for MariaDB - not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so i'm gonna post and delete after you see this.
you put a ',' instead of ';' after your insert into in the fiddle that's why the result 2021-07-01 16:00:00 is shown

Comment: correct! new fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=1a0f32a5a369310bbcfdf8a286d54cc5

Comment: Just an idea : an easier way to do this is to create a new table Freetime and everytime you insert a new event you update the Freetime table by removing the dates which are > the start of the event and < the end (a Trigger)

Comment: that is a possible way. But than I have to create a task, which update the freetime table (perhaps every day or 1x per year) with the new data, correct?

Comment: Yes you're right. Every day / year you will have to insert all new date (before you insert new events).

Comment: can you show me the insert command to fill this table please ? I only know the way like above (Select command)

Comment: I believe this works :
INSERT INTO Freetime SELECT 
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL day.seq DAY), INTERVAL hour.seq HOUR)
FROM 
seq_0_to_0 AS day, 
seq_14_to_18 AS hour

Comment: Error 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=45ab2b4a44eb2a2f953fc6b37b667b48

Comment: you can send me the fiddle link? :) this link doesn't work :/

Comment: Yes i edited the link it works now, i'm dumb lol. Btw you have to change seq_14_to_18 to seq_0_to_24 or whatever you want

Comment: yeah this works, BUT I would like to have additional a column "ID" which is auto increment. Than the insert command doesn't work :( https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=86a8072c5dc2f9d857463bd0334dd583

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=5e397186c5de3e1950e684ae35f93de1

Comment: with the available column : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d619c17bec539f25fc6f6f0ef4be0cd6

Comment: It works perfect ! Thank you very much ! You made my day ! :)